# Jackson Json Deserialization Issues

Tags: json, jackson, deserialization

When trying to deserialize a JSON string, I am getting an exception:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Invalid type id 'subStatus' (for id type 'Id.class'): no such class found (through reference chain: context.ValueBean["valueObject"]->multipleProfiles.ProfileEntries["m_profileDataMap"]->multipleProfiles.ProfileData["contextMap"])
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:218)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:183)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.wrapAndThrow(BeanDeserializer.java:1472)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:699)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.jsontype.impl.AsWrapperTypeDeserializer._deserialize(AsWrapperTypeDeserializer.java:95)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.jsontype.impl.AsWrapperTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsWrapperTypeDeserializer.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeWithType(BeanDeserializer.java:664)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBind(MapDeserializer.java:321)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:249)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:33)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.jsontype.impl.AsWrapperTypeDeserializer._deserialize(AsWrapperTypeDeserializer.java:95)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.jsontype.impl.AsWrapperTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsWrapperTypeDeserializer.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserializeWithType(MapDeserializer.java:273)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:297)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:579)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:697)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.jsontype.impl.AsWrapperTypeDeserializer._deserialize(AsWrapperTypeDeserializer.java:95)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.jsontype.impl.AsWrapperTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromAny(AsWrapperTypeDeserializer.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer.deserializeWithType(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:106)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:297)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:414)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:697)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.jsontype.impl.AsWrapperTypeDeserializer._deserialize(AsWrapperTypeDeserializer.java:95)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.jsontype.impl.AsWrapperTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsWrapperTypeDeserializer.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeWithType(BeanDeserializer.java:664)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider$WrappedDeserializer.deserialize(StdDeserializerProvider.java:461)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2732)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1863)
```

My Jackson Configuration is :

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setVisibility(JsonMethod.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
    mapper.disable(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
    mapper.enableDefaultTyping(); 
    mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);
    mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT); 
    Object jsonObj = null;
    try
    {
        jsonObj = mapper.readValue(objStr, clazz);
    }
    catch (JsonGenerationException e)
    {
        g_log.error(e, e);
    }
    catch (JsonMappingException e)
    {
        g_log.error(e, e);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        g_log.error(e, e);
    }
```

I have been searching for hours for this issue. The problem I see is the map's key is actually a string. But Jackson is considering it as a class and trying to load that class.

Please let me know if I have missed some configuration that causes this issue.

Comment: Balaji, can you also post the JSON string, at least enough of it for us to get an idea of the structure, and also, where are objStr and clazz being declared and defined?